# Why isn't my Ramda pipe function not working with filter?

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, pipe, ramda.js

I have a curried function which I am using in a composition and this works:

```
const getClubs = R.filter(R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))
```

This is taking in an array of card objects and filtering them by their suit.

But when I try to unnest this function call and turn it into a pipe:

```
const getClubs = R.pipe(R.filter, R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))
```

...this doesn't work anymore and I don't even get any errors. What am I doing wrong with my pipe or filter functions?

Here is a [working version of my code](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20deckUrl%20%3D%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fdeckofcardsapi.com%2Fapi%2Fdeck%2Fnew%2Fshuffle%2F%3Fcards%3DAS%2C2S%2C5C%2C3C%2CKD%2CAH%2CQH%2C2C%2CKS%2C8C%27%0A%0Aconst%20log%20%3D%20R.tap%28console.log%29%0A%0Aconst%20getDeckId%20%3D%20R.prop%28%27deck_id%27%29%0Aconst%20drawCards%20%3D%20id%20%3D%3E%20fetch%28%60https%3A%2F%2Fdeckofcardsapi.com%2Fapi%2Fdeck%2F%24%7Bid%7D%2Fdraw%2F%3Fcount%3D10%60%29.then%28res%20%3D%3E%20res.json%28%29%29%0Aconst%20getCards%20%3D%20R.prop%28%27cards%27%29%0Aconst%20getClubs%20%3D%20R.filter%28R.propEq%28%27suit%27%2C%20%27CLUBS%27%29%29%0A%2F%2F%20const%20getClubs%20%3D%20R.pipe%28R.filter%2C%20R.propEq%28%27suit%27%2C%20%27CLUBS%27%29%29%0Aconst%20sortCardsByValue%20%3D%20R.sortBy%28R.prop%28%27value%27%29%29%0Aconst%20pluckImages%20%3D%20R.pluck%28%27image%27%29%0Aconst%20createImageDom%20%3D%20R.compose%28R.join%28%27%27%29%2C%20R.map%28url%20%3D%3E%20%60%3Cimg%20width%3D%22100%22%20src%3D%22%24%7Burl%7D%22%2F%3E%60%29%29%0Aconst%20render%20%3D%20imgString%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20document.querySelector%28%27%23cards%27%29.innerHTML%20%3D%20%60%3Cdiv%3E%24%7BimgString%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%60%0A%0Aconst%20transformData%20%3D%20R.compose%28createImageDom%2C%20pluckImages%2C%20sortCardsByValue%2C%20getClubs%2C%20getCards%29%0A%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%0A%0A%0Afetch%28deckUrl%29%0A%20%20.then%28res%20%3D%3E%20res.json%28%29%29%20%2F%2F%20returns%20promise%0A%20%20.then%28getDeckId%29%0A%20%20.then%28drawCards%29%20%2F%2F%20returns%20promise%0A%20%20.then%28transformData%29%0A%20%20.then%28log%29)

Toggle between line no.8 and line no.9 to see the problem I am describing above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has at least two problems.  First, you're confusing `compose` and `pipe`.  They are very similar, but they apply their functions in the opposite order.

```
pipe(g, f)(x);    //=> f(g(x))

compose(g, f)(x); //=> g(f(x))
```

So if you want an equivalent of `filter(propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))`, then you need to write one of the following instead of `R.pipe(R.filter, R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))`:

```
R.pipe(R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'), R.filter)
// or
R.compose(R.filter, R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))
```

But the second problem is more fundamental.  `pipe` and `compose` do not pass one item of their list of function to another one.  Instead, they return functions in which the first function is called against the data supplied, the second one is called against the result of the first, the third is called against the result of the second, the fourth against the result of the third, etc.

But `filter` needs two parameters, a predicate function and a list of values.

Your `filter(propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))` is passing `filter(propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))`, a function of one argument due to currying, to `filter`, which needs a one-argument function and a list of values.  Because we pass just the first, we get back a function that takes the list of values and filters it down to the matching ones.

When you try, say `pipe(propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'), filter)`, and call the resulting function with a list called `cards`, you pass `cards` to `propEq('suit', 'CARDS')`, and since `cards` is a list without a `suit` property, it returns false.  You then call `filter` with this `false` value.  Since this curried function requires two parameters, you get back a function looking for a second parameter.  It's a useless function, though, because the first argument, `false` is not a predicate function.

I hope that makes sense.  I didn't get much sleep last night, and I'm not quite sure what's sensible.  :-)

Comment: I *sooo* wish other library authors were as active on SO as you are....

Comment: So what is the solution? Stick with `R.filter(R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))`?

Comment: Also I think you miswrote pipe and compose to be the same order `(g, f)(x);` I think

Comment: @AmitErandole: You're asking for a solution, but I don't know what the problem is.  I see absolutely nothing wrong with `R.filter(R.propEq('suit', 'CLUBS'))`.  Why do you want to change it?  It looks no different to me than `map(add(5))`.  You simply pass a partially configured function to another functions.  That feels very natural.

Comment: @AmitErandole: `pipe(g, f)(x); //=> f(g(x))` vs. `compose(g, f)(x); //=> g(f(x))`.  I **think** that's right.  Note that I'm showing how the two functions on the same list of callbacks yield different output.  I could have written it in another way to make my point, but I think they're equivalent:  `pipe(g, f)(x); //=> f(g(x))` vs. `compose(f, g)(x); //=> f(g(x))`.  Either version to me shows the same thing.